# Overlapping lines / wordwrapping CSS

Tags: html, css, text

I want to have a CSS effect of marked words in a text. My first attempt looked good until i had some kind of word wrapping:

```
<html><body>
<p> aaa 
  <span style="background-color:#ff8080;border-radius:8px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px"> 
  bbb 
    <span style="background-color:#80ff80; border-radius:8px;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:4px">
      ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc 
    </span> 
    ddd     
    <span style="background-color:#8080ff; border-radius:8px;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:4px">
      eee
    </span> 
  </span> 
  fff
</p>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Any idea how to get the right line height?

Thank you very much for every hint!

Comment: Did you try setting the css property `line-height`? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell: Yes, I tried line-height as a solution. But sometimes I have more than two layers into each other and I am searching for a general solution. With every additional layer I need a larger line-height.

Comment: I see what your problem is. I guess the layers are generated programmatically, sou you should know how high you have to calculate the line height: `line-height: (20 + numberOfLayers * 5)px`

Comment: Of course! This would be an easys solution. I will do so if I won't have a better one. But look at this: Big text, many lines, but only less marked words. The lines with marked words shall have a greater line-height than the other ones.

Comment: The only other solution would be too set the `z-index` for each container so they do not overlap the containers from the line before. Then you would have a smooth transition form one line to another. **EDIT**: You can't set the z-index from spans without positioning them which would cause them to break into seperate lines. The only idea i've got now is to calculate the top and bottom padding of each marking-container but that would be a really bad practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after discussing the problem with the author the I have this idea for a workaround of your problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<p> aaa 
  <span style="background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);border-radius:8px;padding: 0 4px;"> 
  bbb 
    <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2); border-radius:8px;padding: 0 4px;">
      ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc 
    </span> 
    ddd     
    <span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2); border-radius:8px;padding: 0 4px;">
      eee
    </span> 
  </span> 
  fff
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

You use transparent colors so you dont need the top/bot padding which is your problem.

Comment: This was my very first attempt (just without the transparency). But I WANT to see the surrounding colors of the surrounding markers at top and bottom. But whatever, I will use the easy solution (line-height: (20 + numberOfLayers * 5)px), so I will mark your answer as the right one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I seperated your code into CSS: You can simply use `line-height: 50px;`

```css
.style1 {
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color:#ff8080;
  border-radius:8px;
  padding-top:8px;
  padding-bottom:8px
}

.style2 {
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color:#80ff80;
  border-radius:8px;
  padding-top:4px;
  padding-bottom:4px
}

.style3 {
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color:#8080ff;
  border-radius:8px;
  padding-top:4px;
  padding-bottom:4px
}
```

```html
<p> aaa 
  <span class="style1"> 
  bbb 
    <span class="style2">
      ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc 
    </span> 
    ddd     
    <span class="style3">
      eee
    </span> 
  </span> 
  fff
</p>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Increase the `line-height` in your opening `p` tag, for example like

```
<p style="line-height: 200%;"> ....
```

(Try different values to see what fits best)